# Choice of complex types in an XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype

In an XML schema can a complex type contain a choice of other complex types? I couldn't find any information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [section 3.4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type) of the XML Schema reference; a `complexType` can indeed contain a `choice` element.

Similarly, a `choice` element can contain one or more `complexType` elements (see [section 3.8.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-contentModel)).

Comment: Thanks. I should have looked there in the first hand :-)

Comment: Not quite right. A choice element cannot contain complexType elements. It can contain a choice or sequence model group, or a reference to a named model group.