# How does one describe a choice of sets / complexTypes in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML document similar to the following, where I have two types of elements. The first type can only contain some ordered set of nodes; and the second type can only contain some other ordered set of nodes. These are all intermixed under a root element. For example:

```
<root>
  <!-- any number of Type One and Type Two -->
  <item>
    <type>Type One</type>
    <a />
    <b />
  </item>
  <item>
    <type>Type Two</type>
    <d />
    <e />
  </item>
</root>
```

I would like to describe this document. Is there some form of `<xs:choice>` or similar that allows choosing between `<xs:complexType>`s?

For example, the following describes what I'd like to do, but is not a valid XSD because it fails the [unique particle attribution rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution):

```
<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <!-- failure: violates UPA here -->
      <xs:element name="item" type="Type One" />
      <xs:element name="item" type="Type Two" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="Type One">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="type" type="typeOneId" />
    <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="typeOneId">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Type One" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="Type Two">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="type" type="typeTwoId" />
    <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="typeTwoId">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Type Two" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Hm, OTOH, a `sequence` of 3: Type 1, Type 2 , and then a complextype containing a `choice` of Type 1 & Type 2, and making that complextype minoccurs=0, maxoccurs=unbounded?

Comment: @Wrikken: That's not the structure I want to describe -- the root node contains any number of type `Type One` and `Type Two`.

Comment: OK, misunderstood you then, I thought it was to require explicitly Type 1 first, then Type 2, and then any of them to 0-unlimited. But then I don't really understand your question: is there a choice which can contain complextypes? => [Yes, that would be `choice` itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252175/choice-of-complex-types-in-an-xsd).

Comment: @Wrikken: I updated the question to better describe the issue -- if you just put elements of those types under `xs:choice` then you break the Unique Particle Attribution Rule.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest and technically best approach is to change the XML form you show.  You have two different types of elements; give them two different names.  Your sample would then take some form like this:

```
<root>
  <!-- any number of TypeOne and TypeTwo elements -->
  <typeOne>
    <a />
    <b />
  </typeOne>
  <typeTwo>
    <d />
    <e />
  </typeTwo>
</root>
```

This is easy to define using xsd:choice, but you say you don't know how to do that, so perhaps I should give a simple example (not tested):

```
<element name="root" type="tns:root"/>
<element name="typeOne" type="tns:typeOne"/>
<element name="typeTwo" type="tns:typeTwo"/>
<complexType name="root">
  <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <element ref="tns:typeOne"/>
    <element ref="tns:typeTwo"/>
  </choice>
</complexType>
<complexType name="typeOne">
  <sequence>
    <element ref="tns:a"/>
    <element ref="tns:b"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="typeTwo">
  <sequence>
    <element ref="tns:d"/>
    <element ref="tns:e"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

If we assume that you really meant it when you said you want to validate precisely the document you show, then of course the root type can be more tightly constrained:

```
<complexType name="root">
  <sequence>
    <element ref="tns:typeOne"/>
    <element ref="tns:typeTwo"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

(Of course, if all you care about is that the single document you show be valid, then a schema consisting solely of the declaration `<element name="root"/>` would do fine.  I'm guessing you didn't mean it that way.)

If this is too clear and simple for the system you want to build, and you want to call all the children of root by the same name, in order to make things more challenging, then another approach is to provide a simple label.  There are two types, which we distinguish by two empty flag elements, called flag1 and flag2.  The input becomes:

```
<root>
  <!-- any number of TypeOne and TypeTwo elements,
       but we call them all by the same name -->
  <item>
    <flag1/>
    <a />
    <b />
  </item>
  <item>
    <flag2/>
    <d />
    <e />
  </item>
</root>
```

The relevant part of the schema document could look like this:

```
<element name="root" type="tns:root"/>
<element name="item" type="tns:item"/>
<complexType name="root">
  <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <element ref="tns:item"/>
  </choice>
</complexType>
<complexType name="item">
  <choice>
    <sequence>
      <element ref="tns:flag1"/>
      <element ref="tns:a"/>
      <element ref="tns:b"/>
    </sequence>
    <sequence>
      <element ref="tns:flag2"/>
      <element ref="tns:d"/>
      <element ref="tns:e"/>
    </sequence>
  </choice>
</complexType>
```

Actually, in the sample data you give, no flag elements are needed:  Type One elements always begin with `a`, Type Two elements with `d`.  So the content model of item is a choice between the sequence `a`, `b` and the sequence `d`, `e`.  The flag elements may be useful in more complicated scenarios.  The input becomes:

```
<root>
  <!-- any number of TypeOne and TypeTwo elements,
       but we call them all by the same name -->
  <item>
    <a />
    <b />
  </item>
  <item>
    <d />
    <e />
  </item>
</root>
```

In your comments, you add that you are trying to match the XML for an existing data stream, which looks essentially like the XML you show in your question.  What I said above still holds:  the simplest and best approach is to fix the broken design of the XML.  But if we assume that you cannot or will not persuade the producers of that XML data stream to produce something a little less perversely structured, then your best bet is probably to use XSD 1.1 assertions to constrain the structure.  This makes life harder for other XSD tooling like data binding tools, because understanding the implications of assertions is a lot like proving theorems in a not terribly well understood formal logic, and most data binding tools or editors won't be able to do much with the schema.

But you can validate your input with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/tns"
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/tns"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

  <element name="root" type="tns:root"/>
  <element name="item" type="tns:typeOne-or-typeTwo"/>
  <element name="type" type="tns:typestring"/>
  <element name="a"/>
  <element name="b"/>
  <element name="d"/>
  <element name="e"/>

  <simpleType name="typestring">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="Type One"/>
      <enumeration value="Type Two"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <complexType name="root">
    <sequence>
      <element ref="tns:item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="typeOne-or-typeTwo">
    <sequence>
      <element ref="tns:type"/>
      <choice>
        <sequence>
          <element ref="tns:a"/>
          <element ref="tns:b"/>
        </sequence>
        <sequence>
          <element ref="tns:d"/>
          <element ref="tns:e"/>
        </sequence>
      </choice>      
    </sequence>
    <assert test="(string(./tns:type) = 'Type One' 
                       and child::*[2]/self::tns:a)
                   or
                  (string(./tns:type) = 'Type Two' 
                       and child::*[2]/self::tns:d)">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>
          If the initial 'type' element contains the string 
          'Type One', then the next child should be 
          element 'a' (followed in any valid instance
          by a 'b'); if the initial 'type' element contains 
          the string 'Type Two', then the next child should 
          be element 'd'.  Etc.
        </documentation>
      </annotation>
    </assert>    
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

This does require XSD 1.1 support, which is available from Saxon, Xerces, and XML Spy.

Comment: Unfortunately the "simplest thing" isn't okay because I'm retrofitting a schema onto an existing format which was previously defined as "Whatever library X understands" :(

Comment: Then you probably need to edit your question to make clear what your real constraints are.

Comment: Erm, I think the question is pretty clear. It says "I want to match this document", not "I want to match something that is different than this document."

Comment: `I'm assuming you know how to write content models for all of these.` <-- No, actually I don't know how to do that without running into the Unique Particle Attribution Rule.